# ggplot How to Change the Width of one bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I created this small data frame to mimic the one I'm working with.

```
df <- data.frame( sex = c('male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male'),
                  food = c("hamburger", "hamburger", "pizza", 'pizza', 'hotdog', 'pizza', 'hamburger', 'pizza'))
```

When I make a grouped bar chart one of the bars takes up twice as much room because one of the variables is zero. How can I change the width of that single bar so it is the same as the others?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = food, fill = sex)) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge')
```

[image: bar chart]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position_dodge2` with `preserve="single"` to keep same width like this:

```r
df <- data.frame( sex = c('male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male'),
                  food = c("hamburger", "hamburger", "pizza", 'pizza', 'hotdog', 'pizza', 'hamburger', 'pizza'))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = food, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Add `padding = 0` to remove whitespace between bars:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = food, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0, preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>